# set array_filter to accept null, zero and empty values

Tags: php, laravel

How can I set "array_filter" to accept the null values, empty and zero?

I tried the callback function but it didn't work for me.

Here's my code

```
$student = array_filter($request->student);
    $teacher = array_filter($request->teacher);
    
    $ScID = array_map(null, $student, $teacher);
    

    SchoolDescriptions::where('pin_id', $request->session()->get('pin_id'))->delete();
    foreach ($ScID as $key=>$array) {
        SchoolDescriptions::updateOrCreate([
            'student' => $array[0],
            'teacher' => $array[1],
            'pin_id' => $request->session()->get('pin_id')
        ]);
    };  return back()->withStatus(__('Successfully saved.'));
```

Comment: What is the value of $student and $teacher, there must be an easier way than that. and what are you actually trying to do when assigning $ScID

Comment: values are just strings, I want my form to accept a zero or null value when saving.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution for this. So I just simply made a condition.
To accept null values when submitting teacher and student forms.

```
if ($request->student == null && $request->teacher == null)
{
//do nothing
}
else {
$student = array_filter($request->student);
$teacher = array_filter($request->teacher);
$ScID = array_map($student, $teacher);
SchoolDescriptions::where('pin_id', $request->session()->get('pin_id'))->delete();
foreach ($ScID as $key=>$array) {
    SchoolDescriptions::updateOrCreate([
        'student' => $array[0],
        'teacher' => $array[1],
        'pin_id' => $request->session()->get('pin_id')
    ]);
};
}
```